# What does the notation a (mod b, n) mean?

Tags: algorithm, modulo, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to write a Python program for the [AKS primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test).

The 5th step states `if (X+a)^n≠ X^n+a (mod X^r − 1,n), output composite;` but I'm not sure what to do when the modulo has 2 arguments: `Xr-1` and `n`. In this case, what is it supposed to be calculating?

I understand `a(mod b)` means that the remainder after dividing a number with `b = a`, but not sure what the 2 arguments in this are meant to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X here means that we're working with polynomials. Mod `X^r - 1` means that we mod all of the polynomial exponents by `r`. Mod `n` means that we mod all of the coefficients by `n`.

As an example, if we have a polynomial `X^4 + 4 X^3 + 6 X^2 + 4 X + 1` and we're modding by `X^3 - 1` (i.e., `r = 3`) and `n = 5`, then we get

```
X^4 + 4 X^3 + 6 X^2 + 4 X + 1 -> (mod by X^3 - 1)
X^1 + 4 X^0 + 6 X^2 + 4 X + 1 =
X   + 4     + 6 X^2 + 4 X + 1 =
6 X^2 + 5 X + 5 -> (mod by 5)
1 X^2 + 0 X + 0 =
X^2.
```

Answer (score 2):

It means x^r is congruent to 1 and also n is congruent to 0.

For example, if r=3, then we have x^4 is congruent to x. This produces a polynomial of degree at most r-1.

Use the n congruent to 0 rule on the coefficient of the polynomial.